# css: outrageous change in property when put inside this fieldset

Tags: css, html, padding

My custom drop down menu has a really large change in top and bottom padding.

[**UPDATE** Javascript, CSS & HTML included in fiddle [PHP removed]](http://jsfiddle.net/6gs63/2/)

---

First off, I didn't realise I could share a fiddle ^^
Pretty epic site.

I'ma keep debugging, but thought I'd post it here to see if anyone can spot where the problem is :)

Comment: Could you provide the associated html (and javascript, if necessary) or set up a sample on http://jsfiddle.net. It would be a lot easier to look for an answer...

Comment: sure.   Sorry, I didn't want to include 1000's of lines of code.

Comment: @Dave:    Added code to JSFiddle, I didn't know I could do that!  Awesome site.

Comment: @Callum Don't include PHP in your fiddle - they won't execute on the jsfiddle website. Instead, include the generated HTML copied from your browser.

Comment: @Yi Jiang:   Sorry, i forgot it was in there, its removed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fieldset css you are changing the line-height, which is also applied to the dropdown.

You have to set the line-height in the css for the dropdown:

```
.dropdown,
.dropdown li /* or whatever other selector is also needed */
{
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

EDIT:

That seems to fit quite good:

```
.dropdown,
.dropdown li,
.dropdown span,
.dropdown a {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 3em;   
}
```